# Что нужно изучить для группировки новостей на одинаковую тему

Tags: python

Нужно с помощью программы сгруппировать тему на одну тему (Например есть четыре новости: "Вилсаком уехал в Китай", "Криштиану Роналду победил в хоккей со счетом 1:7", "Криштиану Роналду выиграл в хоккей", "Вилсаком смог переехать в Китай") и нужно объединить первую и четвертую, вторую и третью.

Подскажите, что нужно изучить для выполнения такого задания.

Comment: По какому критерию нужно группировать? Да и что-то мне подсказывает, что анализу подлежат не только заголовки, но и текст новостей.

Comment: Ищите по запросам `Категоризация текстов` или `Классификация текстов`.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5, в частности `LDA`. Лучше, конечно, на текстах, но можно и на заголовках попробовать. А потом уже кластеризацию.